# Combining Two JQuery.Map into one?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, merge

Im doing some calls to the spotify webservice to search for artists and tracks in my personal application.

The problem is that i want to display the two different results in one object.

Is this possible?

Or should i approach in a different way? (get me on track in that case).

Maybe i should do a nested call to the webservice ?(please write some code, i've tried to do it myself, but i really dont know how to get it right)

Jsfiddle for readability and Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a97Ys/

Code below

```
function GetTracks(request, response) {
        $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json", {
            q: request.term
        }, function (data) {
            response($.map(data.tracks.slice(0, 5), function (item) {
                return { label: item.name, by: item.artists[0].name, category: "Track" };
            }));
        });    
}

function GetArtist(request, response) {
    $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json", {
        q: request.term
    }, function (data) {
        response($.map(data.artists.slice(0, 5), function (item) {
            return { label: item.name, by: "", category: "Artist" };
        }));
    });
}
```

This function is the one i have problem with:

```
$(function () {
    $("#ListenToInput").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {           
            //...Combine two maps and return one object ...//
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using autocomplete, it's nice to keep a local cache variable to store results in.  You can use that same cache to combine the track and artist search results like so:

```
var cache = {};

function GetTracks(request, response) {
    $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json", {
        q: request.term
    }, function (data) {
        $.merge(cache[request.term], 
        $.map(data.tracks.slice(0, 5), function (item) {
            return {
                label: item.name,
                by: item.artists[0].name,
                category: "Track"
            };
        }));
        response(cache[request.term]);
    });
}

function GetArtist(request, response) {
    $.get("http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/artist.json", {
        q: request.term
    }, function (data) {
        $.merge(cache[request.term], 
        $.map(data.artists.slice(0, 5), function (item) {
            return {
                label: item.name,
                by: "",
                category: "Artist"
            };
        }));
        response(cache[request.term]);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $("#ListenToInput").catcomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            if (cache[request.term]) {
                return response(cache[request.term]);
            } else {
                cache[request.term] = [];
                GetTracks(request, response);
                GetArtist(request, response);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Autocomplete doesn't seem to complain if the response function gets called twice.

http://jsfiddle.net/jk9s2/